# How to read a excel file from src/test/resources in Java

Tags: java, excel, file, file-io

I am trying to read an excel file for testing from test/resources, but i keep getting the `FileNotFoundException`. I have tried these two approaches, both seem to be giving the same `FileNotFoundException`.

```
File decisionConfig=new File("src/test/resources/mapping.xls");
File decisionConfig=new File("classpath:test/resources/mapping.xls");
```

Comment: Can it just be the wrong path?

Comment: No when i give absolute path,its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test/resources/mapping.xls");
```

This should get the file based upon the `ClassLoader` as long as the `test` directory is in your `src` folder. This will get the `InputStream` for the file.

*********************************UPDATE************************************
For `File` object:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("test/resources/mapping.xls").toString());
```

Comment: I want to set it to only to a  FILE object , since I need to pass a file object as an argument.

Comment: @SatheshBm can you post your folder structure for your project (screenshot)

Comment: But this only works if your test resources are in `src/test/resources`. What if you use a custom path, for example `tests/res`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want do with this file but for Microsoft Office files I like to use Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("test/resources/mapping.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: I am using a rule engine called drools , It accepts only File input. That's the reason.